# React App Problem With "npm start" command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

**After Installing React App, I encountered with this error after running the command "npm start"**

```
Cannot destructure property compile of 'undefined' or 'null'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! tanaaz@0.1.0 start: node scripts/start.js

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the tanaaz@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /Users/****/.npm/_logs/2018-12-06T11_41_02_180Z-debug.log
```

---

Answer (score 0):

**And The Fix for this error is**

- *Add this line to the System Variables - %SystemRoot%\system32*
- *Reboot Your PC*
- Try Running "npm start" command Again. You may now have no issues.

**If You still have some errors**

- Try this commands

1)npm i -g create-react-app

2)create-react-app my-react-app

Now You are Good to GO... :)